# Video In Video View Not Looping For Some Device In Android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I need to loop my video once it stops.I have used the following code.Its working fine in Samsung Phones but its not working in HCL Me U2 Tablet.I am pasting my code below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.mVideoview);
    Video.setVideoPath("/sdcard/Video/Video.mp4");
    Video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    Video.requestFocus();
    Video.start();
    Video.setOnPreparedListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.setLooping(true);
}
```

Please Help Me Immediately!!!

Comment: as a workaround set a onCompletionListener on the videoview and on the callback start playing the video again

Comment: Oh I have tried even that's not working